# GCC asm function with "heapend" assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

As the title stated, regarding in the assembly code heapend, I'm getting an "undefined reference" when I'm linking my program. But heapend is a valid assembly code, what is the reason why I'm getting the error message. By the way I'm using gcc.

```
asm( "heapend" )
```

By the way, I want to calculate the size of the used heap of my program. For example,

```
unsigned int heapsize = asm( /*address of end of the head*/ ) - asm( /*address of end of app*/ );
```

Please take note that asm's function should return the address.

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Comment: You sure that's a valid assembly mnemonic, and not just a macro or something you're used to using?  If so, what assembly language uses it?

Comment: Hi, yeah I guess you are right. It's possible that the heapend is a macro or something. How can I know where is the definition of the macro?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's intended to be a *symbol* that evaluates to the end of the heap, or the address of a variable that stores the address of the end of the heap. Either way it's completely nonstandard. Did you get this from hackish code poking at the implementation details of some system?

Comment: @R: yeah exactly, I thought its a valid assembly code. By they is it possible to know the exact assembly codes to know the end of the head in an application using asm inline function?

Comment: What context is this used for and we may be able to provide you with a replacement mnemonic

Comment: @Earlz: I just want to calculate the size of the heap use of my program. Edited my question. THanks

Comment: @R: Maybe DOS :) If the heap has an end (known apriory!) then it's an OS without swap and virtual addressing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to express just parts of an instruction in asm. You have to either write it completely in C, something like:

```
extern char heapstart;
extern char heapend;
unsigned int heapsize = &heapend - &heapstart;
```

Or complete in assembly:

```
mov [heapsize],heapend-heapstart
```